# How to fix "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stop') at tostop" error?

Tags: javascript, php, wavesurfer.js

I use Wavesurfer.js to play audio items on my website. The idea is to stop the audio when i click on another item. I have this code, but i got error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stop') at tostop" in the console. How to fix it? Thanks!

```
<script>

function toknown(from){
   window.play = from;
}

function tostop( ){
    window.play.stop();
}

</script>

<?php $toto=get_category(57)->category_count; ?>
    <div class="slider slider-nav text-center">

<?php
$ii=1;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 57, 'order' =>'ASC' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <div class="box-vib box-vib<?php echo $ii;?>"  onclick="tostop()">
            <div class="box-vib-music">

            </div>
            <div class="box-vib-nam">
                <?php the_field('name_audio'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php
```

Not sure what to try.

Comment: this error indicates that the variable window.play is undefined

Comment: Yeah, guess so...Could you please suggest how to fix it?

Comment: with what you have supplied, not really. but, you should review the documentation for wavesurfer : https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/